# delete user with non unique id

Tags: linux, useradd

I created a user with non unique id passing `-o -u 1000 -m` option to `useradd` command. So now I have two users with same id but with different names and different home directories.
I thought that this could be a solution to create a new clean environment (for testing purpose) and preserve the same access permissions to some development directories and files.

Although user creation and login in his own desktop environment was successful, one applications, manually started from terminal, was using home directory of original user. So, starting `idea.sh` as ***scantligt_2*** was still using home directory of user ***scantlight***.

***how is this possible? why this application is still using home directory of original user even if I started it as second use?***

here is the content of some environment variables.

```
$> echo $HOME
/home/scantlight_2

$> echo $USER
scantlight_2

$> cd ~
$> pwd
/home/scantlight_2
```

and after all tests,
***Is it safe to delete the user "scantlight_2" with `userdel` command or should I do it manually from `/etc/shadow` file to avoid some conflicts?***

EDIT:
The `idea.sh` is the starting script of "IntelliJ IDEA" IDE. I made a quick recursive `grep` through bin directory content and no usage of getent command was made. Below is the command i used.

```
grep -r -i "getent|passwd" ./idea_install/bin
```

Thankyou.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most programs that need to care about usernames will do a `getent()` lookup to find the UID and use that from then on - that's because users are identified by the uid, the number. The name is not much more than pretty-printing and convenience.

For example, run `id 1000` or `getent passwd 1000` and they will only display the first entry for that uid.

It is not safe to use `userdel` or `deluser` or any similar command to delete that second user.

This is because they will most likely delete the **first** user with uid 1000 that they find.

Instead, you need to edit the passwd and group files manually:

- `vipw` and `vipw -s` to edit `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow`
- `vigr` and `vigr -s` to edit `/etc/group` and `/etc/gshadow`

Comment: my initial idea was to remove the second user providing option `-r` to `userdel` command to automatically remove home directory of second user. Now I think that is a very bad idea :) ... I don't even want to try it to see what will happen. `vipw` and `vigr` are very handy command in this situation. Thankyou.